# Why QueryResultIterator#getCursor() return null in GAE/J

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

The getCursor() javadoc said:

> Returns: a Cursor or null if this query result cannot be resumed

What does the word "resumed" mean in the context?

My code is like below:

```
        com.googlecode.objectify.cmd.Query q = createQuery();
        QueryResultIterator<T> itr = q.iterator();
        while( itr.hasNext() )
        {
            list.add( itr.next() );
        } 
        ... 
       String newCursorValue = itr.getCursor().toWebSafeString();
```

It throws NPE just because itr.getCursor() is emtpy. This method works well for a long time but fails  today when i modify the Query condition(but it is valid). But i can't see why the query condition can affect the getCursor() method.

Anybody please shed some light?
By the way i use GAE/J v1.7.1, Objectify 4a3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should read about [limitations of cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Limitations_of_Cursors). This basically defines when query can be "resumed".

Comment: Thank you Peter, that just clear my question-- the doc say: "Because the NOT_EQUAL and IN operators are implemented with multiple queries, queries that use them do not support cursors, nor do composite queries constructed with the CompositeFilterOperator.or method."

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I was stuck at exactly this.  What's perplexing, though, is that the IN clause works fine in a Unit Test with the LocalDatastoreService test service.  I may file a bug for this!

Comment: Here is an updated link since the content has moved. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/query-cursors#limitations_of_cursors And nother link with a bit more details: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#limitations_of_cursors